# Java/TestNG/Intellij/Behavior Driven Development/Cucumber/Gherkin: Skipped Scenario/Steps

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea, testng, bdd, cucumber-java

I am currently working on a behavior driven frame work for test automation with technologies based on the title (Java, Testng, Cucumber). My problem is that when I run it the tests are not being performed. Instead it's indicating that:

[image: error message]

I'm expecting the output to show the outcome of the tests I've set based on the feature file with respects to the Feature and Scenarios.

Here is the code from the feature file:

[image: image of code snippet]

Here is the code for the steps:

```
import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

public class LoginSteps {

    @Given("user navigates to the facebook website")
    public void user_navigates_to_the_facebook_website() {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
    }

    @When("user validates the homepage title")
    public void user_validates_the_homepage_title() {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
    }

    @Then("user enters username")
    public void user_enters_username() {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
    }

    @And("user enters password")
    public void user_enters_password() {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
    }

    @And("user click on the signin button")
    public void user_click_on_the_signin_button() {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
    }


}
```

I'm following a tutorial on Udemy and the instructor is using Eclipse while I prefer Intellij.  I've referred to similar tutorials on YouTube and Udemy in addition to Google. A response to a similar question seems to indicate that I need to edit configurations and then add the package path to "Glue" configuration.

Link: https://youtu.be/1KmUx0AsHuo

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hrl8Z.png)

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9c77.png)

[Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSDwb.png)

Note: I've attempted different permutations of the path file for the glue configuration with the same results but perhaps I haven't entered it correctly still.

### Update

I tried another permutation of the path to the step file in the form of the absolute path.  Now I'm getting a new error message:

[image]

Comment: Your first try got it right. That exception is expected. Carefully read what is in your step definition.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje Hello, and thank you for your response.  I have reviewed the step definition file but regrettably I'm unable to see how it is affecting my problem.  Test automation is still very new to me, so I'll have to continue examining it and hopefully in time I'll understand.  Again, I thank you kindly for your assistance.

Comment: With what you had on the first try, remove all the `throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();` It's what is causing your test to fail.